# Assign Key Value with another key value in JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I know its possible to set a key value with a preceding key value in Javascript for example

```
var obj = {
            one: "yes",
            two: obj.one
          }
```

obj[two] is now equal to "yes"

How do i go about setting the value when the keys are in a function

```
var obj = {
             one: function () {
                  return(
                     two: "yes"
                     three: ?? //I want to set three to the value of two
                  )
             }
          }
```

I want to have three contain the value of two i.e obj.one() should return {two: "yes", three: "yes"}

Comment: "*I know its possible to `var obj = {one: "yes", two: obj.one}`*". NO, it throws `TypeError: obj is undefined`

Comment: but it is possible to write `var obj = {
   one: "yes"

  }
  obj['two'] = obj.one;`

Comment: that's true, for a weird reason it worked in a one off time in a debugger, weird

Comment: @lboyel, what i don't understand, what do you like to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first code doesn't work neither. It throws `TypeError: obj is undefined`.

You can use

```
var obj = new function(){
  this.one = "yes",
  this.two = this.one
}; // { one: "yes", two: "yes" }
```

For the second one, you can use

```
var obj = {
  one: function () {
    return new function() {
      this.two = "yes",
      this.three = this.two
    };
  }
};
obj.one(); // { two: "yes", three: "yes" }
obj.one() === obj.one(); // false
```

Note each call of `one` will produce a new copy of the object. If you want to reuse the previous one,

```
var obj = {
  one: (function () {
    var obj = new function() {
      this.two = "yes",
      this.three = this.two
    };
    return function(){ return obj }
  })()
};
obj.one(); // { two: "yes", three: "yes" }
obj.one() === obj.one(); // true
```

Comment: this makes sense, curious question why do you have to return a new function, why wont just return and this work, I am guessing you are using a  constructor to help, but I am not clear on why it works that way

Comment: Do you mean `new function(){ ... }`? It creates an empty object and calls that function with the `this` value set to that new object. The object is returned.

Comment: @lboyel The main reason is that when you define each key, they're not meant to be represented in a specific order, or added in sequence. The idea is that it is being "constructed" all at once. So it's theoretically impossible to reference a part of the object that "is already defined" - the object is defined all at once, or at least in no specific order.

Comment: pardon my ignorance, but what i am taking away is that the constructor with the key value object notation works differently compared to the constructor with the new function syntax to create an object because you are able to reference an already defined property "this.two" in this case which is not possible in the prior case?

Comment: @lboyel Yes. You can't reference an object inside its literal definition. But if you instantiate a function, the constructor has a reference to the instance, so it can read previous properties.

Comment: @Oriol got it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var obj = {
    one: function () {
            this.two = "yes"
            this.three = "??"
    }
}

console.log(obj)
console.log(obj.one())
console.log(obj)
```