# reference key inside webpack config.externals

Tags: webpack, configuration

So I have this config-overrides.js file and would like to know if I can re-use the a defined key for other keys? For e.g how LOGIN can re-use API_BASE below?

const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = function override(config, env) {

```
  config.externals = 
  {
    'Config':
      {
        API_BASE : 'http://192.168.0.1',
        LOGIN : API_BASE + '/login,
      }
  }

  return config;
```

}
TIA

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33574465/9083959

Comment: Thanks, I just broke down the JSON objects into two parts.